# How to display the name of an attribute if it is spelled differently in the same table in sql

Tags: sql

Task:

> List all the ‘Student’ Patrons (patron first and last name, and patron type).  If they have a book checked out, include that in the output (book title).  You need to display all the Student patrons, including those that do not have any books checked out.  This will require an OUTER join between the patron and book table.

I have no problem displaying the Patrons name and type or the book checked out until it have to display only the student patrons (this is where the problem is) because the spelling of 'student' is different and I don't know how to display all of them without knowing all of them before hand.

Some of the spellings for 'student' are in all lower case, all upper case or some lower case mixed with some upper case.

Currently this is what my code looks like:

```
select patron.pat_fname, patron.pat_lname, patron.pat_type, book.book_title
from patron
left join checkout on checkout.pat_id = patron.pat_id
left outer join book on patron.pat_id = book.pat_id
where patron.pat_type = 'student'
```

How could I get my code to display all of the student patrons without knowing all of them beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution will vary depending on your database platform and collation settings (case-sensitivity).

Just force `patron.pat_type` to uppercase and then do your comparison.

```
select patron.pat_fname, patron.pat_lname, patron.pat_type, book.book_title
from patron
left join checkout on checkout.pat_id = patron.pat_id
left outer join book on patron.pat_id = book.pat_id
where upper(patron.pat_type) = 'STUDENT'
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't think about this.